# Range of Colors in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm looking to create a cell based coloring system for a datagridview in C#.

Each cell will have a value from -1 through 1. At 0, I'd like the backcolor to be white, at -1 i'd like it to be red, at 1 I'd like it to be green.

In between, I'd like to have it fade between colors. For example, .9 would be green, but not fully green, it would be semi faded toward white. At -.1 it would be mostly white, but have a slight red color to it.

Thanks!

```
private void DGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
//Code to generage pctMove, Lets say its .5 for simplicity...  
double pctMove = .5;                      
e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(pctMove, Color.Green);     
}
```

This does not seem to work for me as the result is a grey color, and then when i click on the cell, it turns into a blue color, which for the life of me i have no idea why.

Comment: have you tried anything sofar?

Comment: So, where is the question here?

Comment: The question is please write my code. Lol

Comment: Sorry - I've tried using Color.FromArgb and changing the alpha based on the percent, IE higher alpha for closer to 1, -1.

This didnt seem to be working though, Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Green) did not give me a faded green color.

Comment: Show us the code please.

Comment: private void DGV_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{

//Code to generage pctMove, Lets say its .5 for simplicity...                        

e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(pctMove, Color.Green);     
}

Comment: Post the code in your question so everyone could read it without searching.

Comment: Sorry - very new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backcolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

"The BackColor property does not support transparent colors unless the SupportsTransparentBackColor value of System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles is set to true."

Mucking with that ControlStyles thing sounds like a quick way to break stuff, so let's do it the dumb way.

```
if(colorVal > 0)
{
    var whiteness = 255 - Convert.ToInt32(colorval * 255);
    myCell.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(whiteness, 255, whiteness); //green
}
else
{
    var whiteness = 255 - Convert.ToInt32(colorval * -255);
    myCell.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, whiteness, whiteness); //red
}
```